# all we have are or is each other

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement, subjects

I heard this phrase in the official call of duty ghosts reveal trailer:

> All we have **is** each other

A quick Google search also reveals about a hundred thousand occurrences, but it sounds really strange to me.

I was under the impression that "we" is plural, and "all" is plural hence it should be

> "all we have **are** each other..."

Can you please explain which is correct?

Comment: It is correct: *we* goes with *have* (plural) and *is* goes with  *each other* (singular, at leat in this context).

Comment: Actually, *is* goes with *all*, but [*all* is a pronoun](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/all?q=all) and is singular when used in that manner.